# How to use idempotent property in Camel File2 component

Tags: java, file, apache-camel

Documentation http://camel.apache.org/file2.html says about limitation in 1000 entities. So if I enable this property what will happened if my cache gets 1000 entities? How to avoid restriction in 1000 entities?
UPDATE
also how to make camel copy duplicates to another folder?

Comment: Can somebody please provide me how to implement idempotent repository in Camel File2 component ?. I have gone through all the documents but I need complete implemention of readLock = idempotent strategy in clustered environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the idempotentRepository and refer to a custom repository where you can store more than 1000 entires in a memory based repository. Or use a file based, or a JDBC based, etc. Or write your own. See the file page for more details.

And also the idempontent consumer eip page, where more repositories is discussed: http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html